# JSON value into FormlyFirldConfig of Formly Form

Tags: angular-formly

I am trying to add a json file formatted to fit the formlyconfig file but unable to do so

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
      <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <formly-form [form]="form"
                     [model]="model"
                     [fields]="fields">
        </formly-form>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my TS file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormlyFieldConfig } from '@ngx-formly/core';
import { CheckListClient, CheckListDTO } from '../../web-api-client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-service-form-formly',
  templateUrl: './service-form-formly.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./service-form-formly.component.css']
})
export class ServiceFormFormlyComponent implements OnInit {
  checklistDtos: CheckListDTO[];
  isEditable: boolean = true;

  constructor(private clientChecklist: CheckListClient, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filterChecklist();
  }

  filterChecklist() {
    this.clientChecklist.getAllCheckList().subscribe(result => {
      this.checklistDtos = result;
    });
  }

  form = new FormGroup({});
  model = {};
  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    
  ];

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.model, null, 2));
    }
  }
}
```

the JSON value is inside this.checklistDtos = result;

Please help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the result in fields, like

```
this.fields = result or 
this.fields = this.checklistDtos
```